# meaning of 'The last thing she ever did'

Tags: grammar

It's [the title of a book](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=lybItAEACAAJ&dq=the%20last%20thing%20she%20ever%20did&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi86KXgosr1AhXKP3AKHd5IBJ8Q6AF6BAgJEAI).

I wonder which of the following two the title means.

1. The thing that was the least likely for her to have done.
2. The final thing she did.

Comment: Almost certainly the second meaning, but titles don't necessarily have to to make sense (or be strictly grammatical).

Comment: The first meaning is conveyed by *The last thing she **would ever do*** (or ***...would ever have done***), not ***...ever did***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the tense of the title being past, this implies that ‘The last thing she ever did’ has happened, meaning it must be the second meaning: the last thing she did before she died.

*Note: As a comment says on your question, it could also have a more poetical meaning.*